# Sorting per row of 2-dimensional array

Tags: c

I have a 2-dimensional(3x7) array. I would like to sort it per row. I have written a sample code.

```
 #define numRows 3
    #define numCols 7
int arr[numRows-1][numCols-1] = {{0,1,2,3,4,5,6}, {7,8,9,10,11,12,13},{14,15,16,17,18,19,20}};

    sort_row(arr);

    void sort_row(int *p)
    {
     for (int i = 0 ;i<numRows-1;i++)
     {
       sort(p[i][]);
     }
    }

    void sort(int *p)
    {
        for ( int c = 1 ; c <= numCols - 1 ; c++ )
        {
            for ( d = 0 ; d <= c - 1 ; d++ )
            {
                if ( array[c] < array[d] )
                {
                    swap = array[d];
                    array[d] = array[c];

                for ( int k = c ; k > d ; k-- )
                    array[k] = array[k-1];      

                array[k+1] = swap;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am doing insertion sort for each row.

Qn: Am i passing the each row into sort properly? How can i improve it?

Looking for suggestion to improve that could improve or point out my mistakes in the code

Comment: Note `d`, `n` and `swap` are undeclared variables.

Comment: Did you test this code? Which is the initial value of `n` in `sort()`? Which are the values of `numRows` and `numCols` ? Why is `arr` dimensioned to `numRows - 1` and `numCols - 1`?

Comment: i corrected the question now....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you really want to implement the sorting yourself, just use `qsort()`.

Comment: do i need to call any header file for that function?if so what?

Answer (score 0):

No; p has been declared a pointer to an int in sort_row, so that p[i] would be an int, which you shouldn't be able to apply [] to, besides which, sort is expecting a pointer to an int.

Also, you have an executable statement (the call to sort_row) outside of any function.

Answer (score 0):

after searching on @unwind ans, came up with this answer:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#define numRows 3
#define numCols 7
int arr[numRows-1][numCols-1] = {{0,1,2,3,4,5,6}, {7,8,9,10,11,12,13},{14,15,16,17,18,19,20}};
int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
  return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}
void sort_row(int *p)
{
 for (int i = 0 ;i<numRows-1;i++)
 {
   qsort (p[i], 7, sizeof(int), compare);//sort(p[i]);
 }
}
```